# Set replace filter in the jboss 6 logging

Tags: logging, jboss6.x

I want to replace some substring in the log. Using JBOSS 6 which has it's proprietary logging.

For example this:

```
<password>myoutstandingpassword</password>
```

to

```
<password>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</password>
```

As far I'm able to filter such row in log by using the filter in jboss-logging.xml.

```
<filter>
<not><match pattern="password"/></not>
</filter>
```

This filter placed in the log handler. This removes the row entirely.

But how to remove only a substring I don't know. Cannot find documentation. Searching source code is rather exhausting.

Note: It should be possible to use Log4j inside JBOSS AS 6 - http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-log/using-log4j-with-jboss-6. In Log4j probably the replacement could be done. I like to implement the replacement without that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I wanted to filter out some data logged by org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor. Implementing log filtering in JBOSS AS 6 was problematic so final solution was to use my own custom LoggingInInterceptor and modify it.

It was done this way:

I created a class extending org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor.

```
public class CXFLoggingInInterceptor extends LoggingInInterceptor {

    private String myCustomLogStringOperation(String logString) {

    ...

    }

    @Override
    protected String transform(String originalLogString) {
        return myCustomLogStringOperation(originalLogString);
    }

}
```

Notice the overrided method **transform**. There you will do the manipulations of text which is then logged!

Then I added an annotation to the web service for which the logging is done. The annotation is **@OutInterceptors** and it will replace the default interceptor(s).

```
@WebService(
    name = ....
    endpointInterface = ....
)
@InInterceptors(interceptors = package.CXFLoggingInInterceptor)
@Stateless(name = ...)
@Remote(....)
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = ....)
public class MyClass implements MyClassInterface

....
```

CXFLoggingInInterceptor is the class we defined at the beginning.